# "Press X to destroy or R to resurrect" during system upgrade

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I am trying to do Ubuntu desktop 12 upgrade to Ubuntu 14 and it is giving me this error at the end :

```
Command terminated with exit status 1
```

Then

```
press x to destroy or r to resurrect
```

what should I do? should I press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

If "x" is selected , then you will come out from the upgrade window without affecting the current settings of the system, and if you choose "r" it will re-launch the window of upgrade where it will ask to continue for upgrade or not.

Comment: What I've found is that pressing either causes the update to fail and leaves behind a broken system.

Comment: Not always broken.. Depends on where it was at in the upgrade. If it hasn't gotten very far, those keys work perfectly as in answer above. But generally agree- session recovery and install 'rewind' have always been lacking during a do-release-upgrade